# Determine red and orange colors in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, colors

I have an array which  has 24 colors in it. What I want to do is to separate red from orange so that they aren't so close in color. I have 4 "red" colors and 4 "orange" colors. What I have noticed is that red always has a lower G value and B value than orange which has higher. So what I want to do is iterate through the array of colors and based on its RGB values determine whether it is red or orange and assign it to `Color.ORANGE` or `Color.RED`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
        if(colorArray[i].getRed() == 255 && colorArray[i].getGreen() <= 20 && colorArray[i].getBlue() <= 20){
            colorArray[i] = Color.RED;
        }
        if(colorArray[i].getRed() == 255 && colorArray[i].getGreen() >= 21 && colorArray[i].getBlue() <= 21){
            colorArray[i] = Color.ORANGE;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the `getGreen` and `getBlue` for red, isn't always going to be lower than 20 it could be that the there is more green in the perceived "red" color however its green and blue values will always be less than the values in the orange color. How can I change this in such away that it uses this logic? 
Here is an example array with colors.

```
Color Array: [java.awt.Color[r=197,g=255,b=106], java.awt.Color[r=197,g=255,b=106], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=25,b=61], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=97,b=112], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=39,b=67], java.awt.Color[r=51,g=255,b=114], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=108,b=113], java.awt.Color[r=197,g=255,b=106], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=254,g=231,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=254,g=231,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=254,g=231,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=79,b=45], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=85,b=51], java.awt.Color[r=197,g=255,b=106], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=51,g=255,b=114], java.awt.Color[r=51,g=255,b=114], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=39,b=67], java.awt.Color[r=51,g=255,b=114], java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=254,g=231,b=255], java.awt.Color[r=255,g=39,b=67]]
```

Comment: Can you just sort them by total amount B+G?

Comment: No, I don't want to sort the array. The order of it matters for what I am working with. @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: I mean sort them purely for the purpose of classification.  You don't have to persist that ordering.

Comment: If that can be done that is alright however I will need to revert back to the original ordering.

Comment: In your if-statement why don't you do `if(colorArray[i].getRed() == 255 && colorArray[i].getGreen() + colorArray[i].getBlue() <= 80)` and `if(colorArray[i].getRed() == 255 && colorArray[i].getGreen() + colorArray[i].getBlue() <= 200)` Of course you can change those values, but they seem good for me. But higher than 200 is more like yellow than orange

Comment: This is a programming related question, which is more relevant than biology. I am trying to separate colors based on RGB values not what the human eye determines them as @JimGarrison

Comment: What your're trying to do is impossible using pure programming logic. Have a look at this table of "reddish" colours: http://www.workwithcolor.com/red-color-hue-range-01.htm  As you'll surely find out, the range of R, G and B varies a lot and it's still determined as red. You can solve your problem only by static comparison, I guess. Know all the possible colour codes and compare them with your array content.

Comment: would I replace my if statements with your comment's if statements ?@SchokokuchenBäcker

Comment: @DiabolicWords in my color array however, I know for a fact that my Red colors blue and green channels will always have a lower value than my orange ones so even if it is reddish I can still determine based on the lower channel values which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is still unclear.  Are you talking about identifying which of your colours is *most* orange (compared to the others), or are you asking about some absolute criteria for determining "orange"?  If it's the latter, can you codify them?

Comment: Your first Idea is what i am working with. I am trying to determine the difference between red and orange. Red has really low G and B values and orange always has higher ones than the ones found in red. So even if the the orange looks just like red I want to assign it to orange just because it has higher G and B channel values than the ones found in red. @OliverCharlesworth . Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to group the colors as to whether it's closer to red than it is to orange, try using the euclidean distance formula within the color space.  The formula is similar to the distance formula in a cartesian plane, with the addition of the z-value.

sqrt((r2 - r1)^2 + (g2 - g1)^2 + (b2 - b1)^2)

Compare the distance from red (255, 0, 0) and orange (255,165,0)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion however I tried that already. My orange and reds are really close to the actual red. I find if I can determine a way to determine red from orange using its 2nd and third channels based on their value it would work better.

Comment: The maths don't lie, this is the formula for determining whether your color is closer to red or orange.  If it's a question of perception, it's not something that you'll be able to solve programmatically.

Comment: I know what you mean. I do this already with it and other colors but I need something more.

`finalStore[0] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], new Color(255, 255, 255)); //white
   finalStore[1] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], new Color(255,50,50)); //orange
   finalStore[2] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], new Color(80, 255, 70)); //green
   finalStore[3] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], new Color(255, 0, 0)); //red
   finalStore[4] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], Color.BLUE);
   finalStore[5] = (int) colorDistance(colorArray[i], new Color(255,255,0)); //yellow`